# How to format the output of a grep with a regex pattern to match between a string and character

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have been working on a bash script that greps occurences of a string from a logFile into an outputFile to monitor its frequency. I want to filter this even further and use the result of that grep to then format a section of the string to be my end result.

Currently my grep is as follows to get the section of the logFile output that I need:

```
grep -n -A 1 "No entry for this particular code type" logFile.txt >> outputfile.txt
```

This gets the full line that starts with that string and will look like the following, with the value of code type changing throughout the logs constantly:
"No entry for this particular code type, code type: 001123." etc.

I want to parse the resulting lines like the above which are outputted from the grep, and just retrieve the value between the string "code type:" and the character ".". 
This would then give me values like 001123

I have been looking online for a solution and nothing that I have tried has worked out. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sed`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) to pull the number out using another regular expression:

```
cat outputfile.txt | sed 's/.*code type: \(.*\)\./\1/'
```

The `\1` references the contents of the `\(.*\)` part of the expression (the first [match group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts)).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `bash` built-in `regEx` support.
Assuming you have your output captured in a `bash` variable

```
$ myString="No entry for this particular code type, code type: 001123."
$ [[ $myString =~ code\ type:(.*). ]] && subString="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
$
$ printf "%s\n" "$subString"
001123
```

(or) if you are OK to use `grep` piped once more for `regEx` capture, do

```
$ <first_grep_command> | grep -Po "code type: \K.*(?=.)"
001123
```

where `-P` flag for supporting only perl style regular expression matching and `-o` to return only the matching string.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked directly in my shell:

```
echo "No entry for this particular code type, code type: 001123." |grep -Po '[0-9]*'
```

meaning that this one could work in your case without too many pipes:

```
grep -Po '[0-9]*' logfile.txt >>outputfile.txt
```